# Java Swap method

Tags: java, arrays, swap

very first quesiton here:
I did a code of swapping an array:

```
class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        int[] arr = {2,3,8,4,1};
        reverse (arr);
        System.out.println(reverse (arr));
    }

    public static int[] reverse (int[] arr) {
        int i=0, j=arr.length - 1;
        while(i<j){
            int temp = arr[i];
            arr[i]=arr[j];
            arr[j]=temp;
            i++;
            j--;
        }
        return arr;
    }
}
```

the printout are supposed to be {1,4,8,3,2}
but it shows "[I@2d98a335" after run, not sure which step is wrong.

Comment: The problem you are seeing is because of the way you are printing the array.  Check out the explanation and solutions in duplink.

Comment: yes, array could not be printed directly. thank you